# Gaussian Processes regression for missing data?

Tags: gaussian-process, data-imputation

Suppose I have data with three dimensions and the joint is $P(X,Y,Z)$. Were Z to be missing on occasion, Gaussian Process regression could infer distributions over these missing values.

But suppose that X, Y and Z were all missing on occasion but at any time, at least one variable was observed.

Can GP regression accommodate this use case?

I see that the authors of this paper used Deep Gaussian Processes for missing data imputation. While I share this case, I suspect that this model design is overkill and a simpler option is viable.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.04648.pdf
https://github.com/BahramJafrasteh/MissingGPs